# Solidity transaction "reverted" when contract is called by another contract

Tags: brownie, solidity-0.8.x

This deposit function works perfectly.  However, when I attempt to call this function from another contract (through an interface), it does all the right transactions, but then reverts at the end, with no message.  No indications whatsoever.

Even the sub_calls() for each of the transactions are identical and it doesn't specify where or why it fails.  It just reverts it.

Here is the deposit function in the first contract -->

```
    function deposit (
        address[] calldata depositTokens,
        uint256[] calldata depositAmounts,
        bytes[] calldata swapdata,
        address userAddress
        )  public payable {


        // This calls the lending pool and deposits the tokens for userAddress
        LendingPool(lendingPool).deposit(depositTokens, depositAmounts, userAddress, 0);

    }
```

This is the second contract function calling the first deposit function -->

```
     // this is the function within the router that is calling the above deposit function. 
     // it passes msg.sender along so the first contract can send back to user (tx.origin)
       
     FirstContractInterface(firstContractAddress).deposit(depositTokens, depositTokenAmounts, 
          depositConnectorData, msg.sender);
```

All of the necessary approvals have been made.

Is there a reason in solidity why this would work being called directly but fail when called with another contract?

Comment: check LandingPool().deposit() code is there anything that cause it to revert?

Comment: Have u give it enough gas ? external contract call might not give an accurate gas estimation.

Comment: I think it about msg.sender, you may check if it exist in function code. Cause that the thing different when call direct vs call by another contract

Answer (score 0):

it should be an external method to be called from outside.